# How can I do column filter with header, the same way we to do row filter in excel

Tags: excel

Need help performing column filter in excel using the header values. what I intend to achieve is that when I select A only A's header should display or when select say F only F header should display.

[image: sample excelfile]

Comment: You need `VBA` to do that otherwise you can use `FILTER()` function if you have Office 365.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `FILTER()` function then you can use below.

```
=FILTER(A1:D7,A1:D1=G1,"No Match")
```

[image]